# Uniform handling of many exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception

In my current project, i am interacting with some 3rd party middleware that throws many different types of exceptions (around 10 exceptions or more).

My library that is using the 3rd party has a few methods, each one interacts with the 3rd party, however needs to be protected from the same set of 10 or more exceptions.

What i currently have is something like this in **every method of my library:**

```
try
{
   // some code
}
catch (Exception1 e)
{
}
catch (Exception2 e2)
{
}
  ...
catch (ExceptionN eN)
{
}
```

The number of exceptions may increase as well.

How can i reduce the code duplication and uniformly handle all exceptions in a single place?

- suppose that the handling in each method in my code is the same.

Comment: Do you need to react in different ways based on each of those exceptions? can you provide some more context? Is this WPF, Winforms, ASP.net?

Comment: Does each exception require specific and different code when handled? e.g. is the code in the catch block for e different than the code in catch block for e2?

Comment: Added more context; hope it helps.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is widely considered a best practice to catch ONLY the exceptions that you want to explicitly do something with.  The approach should be thought of as a compensation for a failure.  For example, an exception occurred and you want to release a connection to a file.  You should also consider making sure that you throw exceptions lower in your code and you handle them higher in your code.

Comment: The context that this code will be executed in, is some form of a Plugin architecture. I need to handle all exceptions and raise some sort of "Failed" flag. The calling code does not need to handle these exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a global exception handler, the implementation depends on your project type (ASP.net -> global.asax, WPF -> App.xaml...)

Or use something like the following :

```
private static void HandleExceptions(Action action)
{
    try
    {
       action();
    }
    catch (Exception1 e)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception2 e2)
    {
    }
      ...
    catch (ExceptionN eN)
    {
    }
}
```

which can be invoked the following way:

```
HandleExceptions(() => Console.WriteLine("Hi there!"));
```

If an exception was thrown during the Console.WriteLine execution, it would then be handled by your exception handling logic

Note that the code to execute might also modify external values:

```
int x = 2;
HandleExceptions(() => x = 2 * x);
```

If you prefer anonymous methods:

```
var x = 2;
HandleExceptions(delegate()
{
  x = x * 2;
});
```

Comment: I thought of creating an "ExecuteSafely" method that will look exactly like this. The lambda notation makes it slightly more cumbersome to write though. Is this common practice? i've never seen it in real use.

Comment: @liortal I've added an anonymous method example if your prefer this syntax

Answer (score 5):

I would start by catching the base `Exception` type and then filtering with a white-list:

```
try
{
   // Code that might throw.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if(e is Exception1 || e is Exception2 || e is ExceptionN) 
    {
         // Common handling code here.
    }
    else throw; // Can't handle, rethrow.
}
```

Now if you want to generalize the *filter*, you can write an extension:

```
public static bool IsMyCustomException(this Exception e)
{
    return e is Exception1 || e is Exception2 || e is ExceptionN;
}
```

and then you can just use:

```
if(e.IsMyCustomException())
{
    // Common handling code here.
}
else throw;
```

You can generalize the *handler* with a simple method:

```
private void HandleCustomException(Exception e)
{
    // Common handling code here.
}
```

If you want to generalize the entire try-catch block, you're probably best off injecting a delegate into a method that wraps the operation, as mentioned by @vc 74.

Comment: Given the extra info provided, think this is the best option - catch base type, perform handling if you can.

Answer (score 1):

how about use one function to handle these Exceptions:

```
try
{
  //Some code here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  if(!ErrorHandler(e))
      return null; //unhandled situation
}

private bool ErrorHandler(Exception e)
{
 switch(e)
 {
     case Exception1:
     //Handle the exception type here
     return true;
     case Exception2:
     //Handle another exception type here
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Can i use an Exception object in a switch statement? how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Enterprise Library 5.0 Exception handling block.  Basically, you define multiple exception types, categories and exception handlers that handle specific exception types.  Ideally, you would define the exception type, hook it up to a formatter and then report the exception using the Logging block.

[You can read all about it here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are some semantic differences between catching and rethrowing an exception, versus not catching it.  Exception filters are therefore very useful, since they allow one to e.g. "Catch Ex As Exception When IsNiceException(Ex)".  Unfortunately, the only way to use them within a C# program is to use a DLL to wrap the necessary functionality (the DLL itself could be written in vb or some other language).  A typical pattern might be something like:

```
  TryWhenCatchFinally( 
    () => {trycode;},
    (Exception ex) => {codeWhichReturnsTrueForExceptionsWorthCatching;},
    (Exception ex) => {codeToHandleException;},
    (ExceptionStatus status, Exception ex) => {finallyCode;});
```

The ExceptionStatus parameter to the "finally" code would be an enumeration saying whether (1) no exception occurred, (2) an exception occurred, but was handled, (3) an exception occurred and was handled, but another exception was thrown, or (4) an exception occurred but CodeWhichReturnsTrueForExceptionsWorthCatching returned false; (5) an exception occurred which was not handled within trycode, nor handled by this block, but trycode completed anyhow (a rare situation, but there are ways it can happen).  The Ex parameter will null in the first case, and contain the appropriate exception in others--potentially useful information to have if an exception occurs while processing the finally block (stifling an exception that occurs in a finally block may be bad, but if the earlier exception isn't logged or lost before the new exception escapes, all data from the earlier exception will generally be lost; if the same condition which caused the earlier exception caused the later one, the earlier exception might have more useful information about what went wrong).

BTW, a few notes with this pattern:

1. The code that decides whether to catch an exception will run before nested finally blocks execute; it may capture useful data for logging (the fact that finally blocks haven't run may make available for logging information which would get destroyed by nested finally blocks), but actual cleanup should typically be done after finally blocks have run.

   At present, it seems like exceptions that would escape from filters get stifled, but I'm not sure that behavior is guaranteed. Operations which might leak exceptions should probably not be done within filters.

   If the "trycode" contains a try-finally block that's nested within a try-catch block, an exception which occurs in the "try" part of that try-finally block is not handled by the TryCatchWhenFamily nor any nested scope, but is handled by an outer block, and the processing of the inner try-finally block throws an exception which the inner try-catch block handles, the exception which the outer block had decided it was going to catch might disappear without ever being caught.  If the TryWhenCatchFinally method is coded to detect this condition, it could let its finally block code know about that (the finally block may or may not want to do anything about the condition, but it should probably at minimum be logged).

Comment: This method of handling exceptions is hard to read and understand.

Comment: @liortal: It'd be 1000x better if C# simply supported exception filters and/or provided a means by which code in the "Finally" block could know what was going on.  I'd consider something like `Catch Ex As Exception When TypeOf(Ex) Is ThisException OrElse TypeOf(Ex) Is ThatException` to be clearer than any similar construct available in C#.  Code which uses filters for logging is less clear, even in vb, but can log some things that really can't be logged as well without using filters.

Comment: What language supports this feature then?

Comment: @liortal: VB supports exception filters directly, while C# provides no means of accessing them (except by wrapping delegates in a DLL produced in a language which does).  The above syntax is a perfectly legitimate way of using one 'catch' to handle two types of exception in vb; an alternative form could be `Catch Ex As Exception When ExceptionIsNotReallyEvil(Ex)`, where ExceptionIsNotReallyEvil can examine an exception (and possibly InnerException) and determine whether to catch an exception.  I haven't figured out what the cleanest way is of letting the Finally block know if an exception...

Comment: ...is pending; unfortunately, support for that is provided in neither the language nor in the CLR even though both should be able to provide it.  If a 'finally' block is unable to perform its cleanup following an exception in the 'try' block, both exceptions should get logged; the only good way for that to happen is for the 'finally' block to know what exception (if any) is pending when it starts.